# Unescaping html in mailer notification ruby

Tags: html, ruby, render, actionmailer, unescapestring

How to avoid unescaping HTML in below render tag.

nofiy_user.html.erb:

```
<%= render partial: "mailer_notifier/paragraph", :locals => {:asHtml => asHtml, :htmltext => I18n.t('notifications.you_added_user', resource_type: @resource_type, role: @role, resource_name: @resource_name) + ":"} %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with 'raw' method. Something like this,

```
<%= render partial: "mailer_notifier/paragraph", :locals => {:asHtml => raw(asHtml), :htmltext => I18n.t('notifications.you_added_user', resource_type: @resource_type, role: @role, resource_name: @resource_name) + ":"} %>
```

I've assumed that you wanted to unescape asHtml value in mailer_notifier/paragraph. If your need is different than my assumption then you may consider using 'raw' method as appropriate.